# Why doesn't my favicon display on my template page but does on my index page?

Tags: html, favicon

[Click here for template page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lraD9.jpg)

[Click here for index page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u39Sr.jpg)

The favicon displays on the index page , the same code is on the template page but doesn't display the favicon(and the directory is declared ../recources) I've tried many articles and worked with a colleague but still can't find the problem.
Thanks for your time,
Ayaan
Template section:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html >
<head>
    <div class="background-test"> </div>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content="Saturn Studios offers a wide range of website templates!">

 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../recources/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="../recources/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../recources/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="../recources/favicons/favicon-96x96.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../recources/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
 <link rel="manifest" href="../recources/favicons/manifest.json">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="../recources/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../recources/styles/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../recources/styles/queries.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../recources/styles/grid.css">
 <title>Website Templates</title>
</head>
</html>
```

Index (this one works)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content="Saturn Studios is here to take your website idea to the final frontier.">

 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="recources/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="recources/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="recources/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="recources/favicons/favicon-96x96.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="recources/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
 <link rel="manifest" href="recources/favicons/manifest.json">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="recources/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recources/styles/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recources/styles/queries.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recources/styles/grid.css">
 <title>Saturn Studios Official</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Please put in the code as a snippet instead of an image. It will be easy to debug code in the snippet. Or provide a codepen link

Comment: I've done that , just check it

Comment: div elements are not valid in the head of an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ./resources/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png as path.

Comment: For all of them ? or this specific one

Comment: also check what errors you getting in the console and share it with us.

Comment: I fixed the problem , the div shouldn't have been in the head of the template section page...